# (Cygwin) C program linked to custom header file having memory problems when trying to execute

Tags: c

I am using Cygwin. I have two files in the same directory, test.c and iah202_graphics.h. test.c uses functions from the header file, where I have used #include "iah202_graphics.h". I have added the Cygwin directory to my Environment Variables (PATH) already.

However I receive these errors for every function call:

```
$ gcc -o test test.c
/cygdrive/c/Users/Matthew/AppData/Local/Temp/cclm2bNk.o:test.c:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `draw_line'.

/cygdrive/c/Users/Matthew/AppData/Local/Temp/cclm2bNk.o:test.c:(.text+0x27): relocation truncated to fit: 
R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `draw_line'.
/cygdrive/c/Users/Matthew/AppData/Local/Temp/cclm2bNk.o:test.c:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to 
`draw_line'.

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status.
```

It's having trouble linking to the header file even though I've simply stated which file to use in the local directory. I don't understand what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you linking the library or obj file that supplies that function?

Comment: `gcc -o test -I./ test.c` to specify the include directory maybe

Comment: @RetiredNinja the obj header file. That's all they have given us to use. We have two files called iah202_graphics.h and iah202_graphics.c. I presumed only the .h file mattered which is why I am trying to link it to that.

Answer (score 2):

`Undefined reference to 'blah'` is a *linker* error rather than a compiler error and is almost *always* caused by not including a needed library.

Including a header file in your source file does *not* usually link in the code required to provided the functions declared in that header.

For example, were you to prevent linking of the C runtime library, you could include `stdio.h` as many times as you wanted to, and *still* not be able to resolve `printf`.

Bottom line, you generally need two steps:

- include the relevant header file in your source code so it knows about the *declarations* of things provided; and
- link against the relevant library or object file so it has access to the *definitions* of the things provided.

That *could* be something as simple as:

```
gcc -o test -I/path/to/iah202includes test.c -L/path/to/iah202libs -liah202
```

where `-I` indicates where include files can be found, `-L` adjusts the search path for library files, and `-l` actually specifies the library file to use.

---

Even *simpler* is if you have the source file for the graphics stuff (which seems to be the case based on your comments). In that case no library is needed, you can simply use:

```
gcc -o test test.c iab202_graphics.c
```

and that will compile *both* those translation units then link them together.

Comment: is the `-I/path/to/iah202includes` the directory location to the folder with the header & test.c file in it? is this the exact same directory as: `-L/path/to/iah202libs`?

Comment: This is my current code: `gcc -o test -I/"F:\University\IT, Semester 2\CAB202\Weekly Exercises\Topic 2" test.c -L/"F:\University\IT, Semester 2\CAB202\Weekly Exercises\Topic 2" -l/cab202_graphics.h
` and this returns `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/6.4.0/../../../../x86_64-pc-cygwin/bin/ld: cannot find -l/cab202_graphics.h`

Comment: @mattappdev, you *don't* use `-l` to specify include files, it's for libraries only.  As per the answer, the include files and lib files are totally different (but related) beasts. You would be using something like `-L /path/to/libs -l iah202` if the library file name was something like `/path/to/libs/libiah202.sl`.

Comment: I don't want to include any library though? Just a header file that they have included for us to use. How could I link my test.c file to iab202_graphics.h (the header file), that is all I am trying to do.  There is also a iab202_graphics.c file included but I have read that you only need to link to the 'header' to use these functions.

Comment: @mattappdev If you want to use function from a library, you have to include the library with `-l` when linking. If you however have the code for the library (`iab202_graphics.c`), then you have to add this file to your project and compile it as part of your project. Then when you can do `gcc test.c ab202_graphics.c -o test -I<whatever> <other gcc options>`